# Is it possible to attach permissions to content parts in Orchard CMS?

Tags: c#, orchardcms

Let's say I have a content type called Seminar. The Seminar type has three parts welded to it- Room, Schedule, Subject.

When a user edits a Seminar, they will be shown the editor templates for those three parts.

What I would like to do is add permissions to each of the parts so that we can restrict which users can edit which parts. For example, someone with a Scheduler role will be able to view/edit the schedule part, but not the others.

Is this possible out of the box? If so then how can I do this?

If I can't do this out of the box then is anyone aware of a module that I can use to achieve this?

And finally- if there is nothing available that can do this, can anyone point me in the right direction to implement this myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In code, you can check any permissions you want, including your own custom permissions, from the part's driver, and prevent it from displaying anything. Even if it's not your part, you can intercept shapes and prevent them from being displayed, from a shape table provider. But there is no module that I know of that lets you choose permissions for parts without writing code.

Comment: Of course. This answer is so obvious I just looked straight past it. See you in Amsterdam!